# Processing of numbers with fractions in bash with sed or others

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need to process a bunch of text files containing numbers in the form of 1,56728.
The original values are in cm which I need to convert into 72dpi
(`num * 0,393700787402 * 72`).

The original values are in this format `X= 1.767 Y= 1.5`.

I tried `sed s/[^0-9]` to find the numbers, but it did not work.

Should I use sed and if yes, how can I do the computation?

Comment: Have a look at the [binary calculator](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ubc.htm) if you're using GNU/Linux. Might be what you're looking for. I think it uses your environment variables to detect what the decimal sign is.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines. This is not that sort of problem and so no you should not use sed. For all other text manipulation, like this, you should use awk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `awk` for this, it does floating point calculations (bash doesn't) and can handle your file format easily.

```
$ awk -F'[= ]+' \
 'function dpi(x){return x*0.39*72}{print $1"= "dpi($2)" "$3"= "dpi($4)}' \
 input_file
```

The `-F'[= ]+'` part tells awk to split columns on space or equal signs. The function `dpi` does the conversion for one input. The main block prints out the converted values, with the original variable names. Adjust to your liking.